# Value of optional type String? not unwrapped with text.toInt

Tags: ios, swift

This is my first Swift experience. I am following an example in the book Swift by Example, and apparently there is a typo as I copied the code from the author's github [site](https://github.com/gscalzo/GuessTheNumber).

Here's the relevant code that seems to be causing the problem. I am getting this error:

> Value of optional type String? not unwrapped

in this line: let number = numberTxtField.text.toInt() .

```
 @IBOutlet weak var numberTxtField: UITextField!

   @IBAction func onOkPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let number = numberTxtField.text.toInt()
        if let number = number {
            selectedNumber(number)
        } else {
            var alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Enter a number", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Could someone kindly explain how to fix this as this is Day One for me with Swift and I'm still trying to digest symbols like ! and ? and ??

I've read other questions like this one but they didn't seem to help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In **Swift 2.0** you can use the initializer for an integer, for example

```
let number = Int(numberTxtField.text!)
```

Actually probably safer to do:

```
if let text = numberTxtField.text {
    let number = Int(text)
}
```

Comment: Int(numberTxtField.text!)

Comment: @LeoDabus true, force unwrapping is needed in this case

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it seemed more streamlined but the answer provided by the_critic also worked. Both introduced a warning on this line:              var alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Enter a number", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
 but accepting Xcode's suggestion to add a let in front of this statement enabled me to build the code successfully. Now, on to reading more about optionals. Thanks everyone.

Comment: `Int(str)` also returns an optional that must be unwrapped as well. How about `if let text = numberTxtField.text, number = Int(text)`

Comment: If we write Stack Overflow answers which make use of the force-unwrap operater willy-nilly like this, we'll be communicating the idea to those who do not know any better that doing this is acceptable.  Swift 2.0 added even more tools to eliminate few of the legitimate excuses I had heard for even using it in the first place, and I'm unsure why it continues to exist in the language at this point..

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, that `UITextField`'s text value is optional, which means that it could be nil (Check out the [Apple Docs for Optional Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID445)).

In order to use the text value, you will actually need to unwrap it.

Something like this will give you your actual text:

```
numberTxtField.text! // unwraps the value of the optional
```

Watch out though! In case the text value is `nil` the exclamation mark will crash your application.

So to be more careful, only use the value if it exists, like so:

```
if let text = numberTxtField.text{
    yourInt = Int(text)
}
```

This will actually check if the value is set, and if so, assign it to the variable text.

Good luck with Swift!